# How does the or operator work in this case?

Tags: javascript, syntax, operators

var v;
v = (v || 0) + 3;

While learning javascript I ran into this. Does anyone know how it works, what it's called, etc.

Comment: It's just the OR operator, with its operands grouped together in a typical set of parentheses. The result is added to `3`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If both this statement comes right after the other then it doesn't make much sense.. It just means this

```
var v; //which is undefined here

if(!v) //which is true in this case..
{
  v=0; //initialize v=0;
}
v +=3; //Now increment v here as if it doesn't know what v was.
```

and guess what this set of statement will just output **3** always.

Just replace this with `var v=3` :)